# Ruby challenge - shape inheritance

Tags: ruby

learning Ruby. I'm presented with this code challenge:

Create classes to represent a square, rectangle and circle. You should be able to calculate the area of each shape. (There's also a part about being able to set a color as well as inherit the default color, but that's not the part I'm stumped on, so I won't include the specs here.)

The classes should also be able to call a `can_fit?` method which evalulates two shapes and returns true or false based on one shape fitting inside the other.

So I've created the shape class just fine and am calculating the areas of square, rectangle and circle just fine.

But I'm completely stumped on the `can_fit?` method. I'm supposed to include it in the `Shape` class but how do I compare if one shape fits inside another in the `Shape` class if we're using area to compare, and `Shape` doesn't have access to area??

```
class Shape
  attr_accessor :color
  def initialize(color="Red")
    @color = color
  end

  def can_fit?(shape)
    DEFINE METHOD
  end

end

class Rectangle < Shape

attr_accessor :color, :shape, :width, :height

def initialize(width, height, color="Red")
  super(color)
  @width = width
  @height = height
end

def area
  @width * @height
end

end

class Square < Rectangle

  def initialize(width, color= "Red")
    super(width, width, color)
  end

end

class Circle < Shape
attr_accessor :color, :shape, :radius

def initialize(radius, color= "Red")
  super(color)
  @radius = radius
end

def area
  Math::PI * (radius ** 2)
end

end
```

RSpec tests:

```
describe "Shape" do
   describe "can_fit?" do
     it "should tell if a shape can fit inside another shape" do

     class A < Shape
       def area
         5
       end
     end
     class B < Shape
       def area
        10
       end
     end
     a = A.new
     b = B.new
     b.can_fit?(a).should eq(true)
     a.can_fit?(b).should eq(false)
  end
end
```

Comment: your square is not a square but a rectangle. Try `s = Square.new(10);s.height = 15; # height != width`

Comment: Interesting. That didn't raise an issue. Why is my square not a square but a rectangle? If I'm using rectangle's width for all sides of the square why would that matter?

Comment: one cannot conclude `can_fit?` using `area` alone. For e.g. a triangle with 27 sq.cm (area) cannot fit a square of 25 sq.cm (area) even though triangle's area  is bigger than the square.

Comment: The sole purpose of having a square class would be to enforce the invariants of a square. Ie that the height is equal to the width. If that's not enforced why have a sqaure after all all computations you can do on a square are the same that if you did them on a rectangle. Letting square derive from rectangle is a standard textbook example of violating the lisskov substituion principle. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle#A_typical_violation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby doesn't mind that `Shape` doesn't have an area method. It only cares about how an object behaves at the instant of evaluation. In the case of the `can_fit?` method below, `self` is an instance of Square and `other_shape` is an instance of circle. Both have an area method. So, great! If `other_shape` was some other object entirely, it would still work as long as it had an `area` method.

E.g. (ignore the 'calculations' here!)

```
2.0.0-p195 :001 > class Shape
2.0.0-p195 :002?>   def can_fit? other_shape
2.0.0-p195 :003?>     area > other_shape.area
2.0.0-p195 :004?>   end
2.0.0-p195 :005?> end
 => nil 
2.0.0-p195 :006 > class Square < Shape
2.0.0-p195 :007?>   def area
2.0.0-p195 :008?>     2
2.0.0-p195 :009?>   end
2.0.0-p195 :010?> end
 => nil 
2.0.0-p195 :011 > class Circle < Shape
2.0.0-p195 :012?>   def area
2.0.0-p195 :013?>     1
2.0.0-p195 :014?>   end
2.0.0-p195 :015?> end
 => nil 
2.0.0-p195 :016 > Square.new.can_fit? Circle.new
 => true
```

And then...

```
2.0.0-p195 :017 > class Cat # doesn't inherit from anything
2.0.0-p195 :018?>   def area
2.0.0-p195 :019?>     1.5
2.0.0-p195 :020?>   end
2.0.0-p195 :021?> end
 => nil 
2.0.0-p195 :022 > Square.new.can_fit? Cat.new
 => true
```

Comment: "The classes should also be able to call a `can_fit?` method which evalulates two shapes and returns true or false based on one shape fitting inside the other." That can't be determine from areas.

Comment: No--I'm not saying they can. Not at all! I took OP's question to be about how a method in a superclass can access methods in subclasses (or anywhere else) without prior knowledge of those methods, like it would need in a strongly-typed language. A `can_fit?` algorithm isn't a ruby question, really.

Answer (score 0):

A naive solution would be to see if both the height and width of one shape are less than, or equal to, the height and width of the shape you're trying to put the first shape into.

For the circle, the width and height would both be the diameter of the circle.

I said "naive" because I don't know whether you can rotate these shapes or not to fit them in.  (A 4x6 rectangle *does* fit inside a 7x5 rectangle, but only if you're able to rotate the rectangle.)  If so, then you might need to calculate other dimensions, like perhaps the diagonal of the rectangle.

I know that you're doing Ruby, but you might need to be careful about looking at exactly what inheritance means in Ruby.  One of Scott Meyers' books on C++ used this exact example to show how the mathematical model ("a square is also a rectangle") breaks down in the face of C++ inheritance.  A derived class Square from a class Rectangle cannot be expressed with the same elegance as the mathematical definition.  I don't know the answer to that one for Ruby, but you'll want to look at it (as long as you're learning).

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to create a new class Area with the defined method and call Shape into that? Just a thought

Comment: I think it wants me to put it inside the Shape class only. In the code challenge hints, it says: Define a parent class, named Shape, which all other classes will inherit from, either directly or indirectly. We mentioned that the `can_fit?` method should be available to all classes, so the Shape class would be a smart place to define it.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have

```
c = Circle.new(2)
r = Rectangle.new(2,3)
```

Now let's add the following method to `class Shape`:

```
def self_check
  puts self
end
```

Sending this method to `c` and `r`, we get the following:

```
c.self_check # => #<Circle:0x007fd71927fc98 @color="Red", @radius=1> 
r.self_check # => #<Rectangle:0x007fd71925e368 @color="Red", @width=2, @height=3>
```

So even though `self_check` is in the parent class, `self` is the instance of the subclass that calls it.  That means that `can_fit?(other_shape)` has access to both the shape instance `self`, as well as to the argument `other_shape`. We therefore can do the following 1:

```
def can_fit?(other_shape)
  case self
  when Circle
    case other_shape
    when Circle
      self.radius <= other_shape.radius
    when Rectancle, Square
      self.radius <= [other_shape.width, other_shape.height].min
    end
  when Rectangle
    case other_shape
    when Circle
    ...
    ...
```

To see if the particular instance instance `c` would fit in the particular rectangular instance `r`, we would execute:

```
c.can_fit?(r)
```

1 Note that the case statement uses the `===` operator, as opposed to `==`, which is used by `if/then` constructs.  That is why `case` can evaluate whether `self === Circle` is true.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define a can_fit? method in Class Shape that uses self.area compared to other_shape.area

since you already have an area for each class:

```
def can_fit?(other_shape)
  self.area > other_shape.area
end
```